# Data circulating with UART in STM32

Tags: stm32, uart, hal

When I initialize my stm32 i add a 5 second delay and then transmit a 13 bytes long uint8 array over UART. On the reception side, I have my HAL_UART_Receive_IT in the main loop (before while) and then another call to the same function in the Receive complete callback. Additionally, I am also displaying my rx buffer through a tft LCD in my main loop which is set to update after every 1 second.
When i reset my transmission MCU, at first i get my data in the right order but then my data order gets screwed up. so for example, if i send 1234, I get 1234 at first and upon the next reset of my transmission MCU, i get 3412.
why is my data circulating like this and what can i do to prevent this from happening.
Tried reading the reference manual to find the answer but to no avail. Please help!
~a noob coder

Resetting again and again and searching on youtube and other forums

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To get help on here, you need to post your code (not a picture of it) so someone can copy and paste and work with it in order to try to help you.  If there are any error messages, those are critical to be posted to the question as well.  Good luck!

Comment: Try [this example](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/Getting_started_with_UART) to see is there any difference from your implementation?

Comment: Because you need some kind of synchronisation. Especially if you'll randomly reset one half of your kit.